# Remote MySQL database connection Laravel 5 not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5, remote-access

I'm using laravel 5. i need to get some data from a remote MySQL database.

i've already set up my database connection in config/database.php.
This is how it looks:

```
'connections' => [

    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],

    'remotemysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', '************'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'osys'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'Syn'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', '****************'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
],
```

The connection info is correct, i already tested it and i'm able to connect to the remote database.

To test it out i just fetched the database connection and the data in my controller to send it to a view to check whether or not everything is working alright. This is my controller:

```
...
use DB;
...

public function item()
{

    $items = DB::connection('remotemysql')
    ->table('ip_products')
    ->get();
    return view('admin.item', compact('items'));
}
```

and this is my view:

```
...
<tbody>     
 @foreach ($items as $item)
    <tr>
       <td>{{$item->id}}</td>
    </tr>
 @endforeach
</tbody>
...
```

When i try to load my view i get this error message:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dvs.ip_products' >doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `ip_products`)

The error shows me that Laravel tries to get the table form the dvs database (wich is the main site database). So it isn't using the connection 'remotemysql'. If it couldn't connect to the remote database it would have got a connection error but i think its not using the remote connection at all.

What can i do to fix this issue ?

Comment: look at `.env` file in root folder of Your app (:

Comment: Stuff that's in your .env file will always overwrite your config.

Comment: @Taacoo So if i remove the credentials out of my .env and just put it in the database.php it should work ?

Am i not going to wreck it ? :P

Comment: @Pieter-Jan it will be ovewriten by second argument of `env()` functions

Comment: @Pieter-Jan Check the answer given. If you empty the env variables. Or add the config data to the env file it should work like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As You can see from error:

> Table 'dvs.ip_products' >doesn't exist

where `dvs` is database name.

so according to Your config files:

```
'remotemysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', '************'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'osys'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'Syn'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', '****************'),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
],
```

`env()` method has 2 args: `$key, $default`

so it looks first to `.env` file to find `$key` in You case `DB_HOST, DB_DATABASE...` and if it's not defined will use `$default` that You define as second argument.

You can read about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration)